# Images are blocked in outlook how to fix it?

Tags: html, ruby, outlook, gmail, html-email

How to fix the blocked images for outlook.

When i inspect it show me **blockedimagesrc** whereas it should be **src**.

It is working fine in gmail.
[image: Attaching image for reference]

I'M expecting the images to work perfectly in outlook

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: The image blocking is an Outlook feature. The only way around is to send it as an attachment and reference it as CID. See Eugene's example below.

Comment: This is normal for Outlook desktop. It's not an issue that you have to work around. It's a built-in feature for Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook may block external images in message bodies. If you want to be sure that your images are displayed correctly you need to use embedded attachments instead. For that you need to attach an image and refer to it in the message using a special prefix (`cid:`). For example:

```
<img src="cid:{filename}" width="500" height="500">
```